# mostrar y ocultar menu responsive con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Necesito que en tamaño mobile 768 px el boton de menu se active y active, popr el momento solo hay la opcion de activar.

```js
function mobile(){

  var uno = 1;
  var element = document.getElementById("idMobile");
   
  if(uno > 0){
   document.getElementById("idMobile");
    element.classList.add("mobile");

  return uno;
  } else  {
  // document.getElementById("idMobile");
  element.classList.remove("mobile");
  }

}




   // alert("hola");
    // var mobile = document.getElementsByTagName("ul").style.display = "block";
    // document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    // .style.display = "block";
    // document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #00316b;

}
ul{
    width: 80%;
    margin:  0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul li:hover{
    background: #e91e63;
}
ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.toggle{
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #001f44;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    .toggle{
        display: block;
    }
    ul{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    ul li{
      
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        
    }
    .mobile{
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav>
    <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="mobile()"></i>
    </div>
    <ul id="idMobile">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portafolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres conseguir, ¿quieres que al darle al icono de menú cuando es inferior a 768px, el menú se vuelva a  esconder?

Comment: en el tamaño 768 px hay un boton menu, quisiera al darle click me muestre los items y luego en un segundo click se oculte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente lo que deberías hacer en la función `mobile` seria algo asi:

```js
function mobile(){
  document.getElementById("idMobile").classList.toggle("mobile");
}




   // alert("hola");
    // var mobile = document.getElementsByTagName("ul").style.display = "block";
    // document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    // .style.display = "block";
    // document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #00316b;

}
ul{
    width: 80%;
    margin:  0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul li:hover{
    background: #e91e63;
}
ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.toggle{
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #001f44;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    .toggle{
        display: block;
    }
    ul{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    ul li{
      
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        
    }
    .mobile{
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav>
    <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="mobile()"></i>
    </div>
    <ul id="idMobile">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portafolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente puedes hacer un `toggle` a la clase `.toggle`:

```js
function mobile() {
  
  document.getElementById("idMobile").classList.toggle("toggle");
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #00316b;

}
ul{
    width: 80%;
    margin:  0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul li:hover{
    background: #e91e63;
}
ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.toggle{
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #001f44;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    .toggle{
        display: block;
    }
    ul{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    ul li{
      
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        
    }
    .mobile{
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav>
    <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="mobile()"></i>
    </div>
    <ul id="idMobile">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portafolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function mobile(){
  var element = document.getElementById("idMobile");
 element.classList.toggle("mobile");
}//end function mobile
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #00316b;

}
ul{
    width: 80%;
    margin:  0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul li:hover{
    background: #e91e63;
}
ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.toggle{
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #001f44;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    .toggle{
        display: block;
    }
    ul{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    ul li{
      
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        
    }
    .mobile{
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav>
  <div class="toggle">
    <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="mobile()"></i>
  </div>
  <ul id="idMobile">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portafolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Saludos puedes usar toogle para agregar/remover la clase deseada, para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar: [Toogle JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)